# Como trabalhar com o serviço $http do AngularJS de forma síncrona?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, post

Como trabalhar com o serviço $http do AngularJS de forma síncrona?

Nesse caso eu tô usando AngularJS + Laravel e 3 tabelas pra salvar um questionário (em que uma avaliação tem várias questões, e cada questão tem vários itens):

- avaliations (id, user_id, project_id, processed);
- avaliation_questions (id, avaliation_id, question_id, average, obs);
- avaliation_question_items (id, avaliation_question_id, question_item_id, value);

Observação: o backend (laravel) funciona perfeitamente em testes avulsos, mas quando coloco o $http.post dentro do for não salva todos os itens das questões e nem todas as questões... e aí retorna várias vezes o erro:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/teste/api/avaliation_question/create 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/teste/api/avaliation_question/create. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://teste.localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

Meu código (trecho do controller onde tem os `$http.post`):

```
$scope.save = function () {

    // table avaliations
    $scope.avaliations.user_id = $scope.currentUser.id;
    $scope.avaliations.user_valuer_id = $scope.valuer.id;
    $scope.avaliations.project_id = $scope.project.id;
    $scope.avaliations.processed = 0;
    $scope.avaliations.send = 0;

    // begin save avaliations ----------------------------------------------
    $http.post(ApiUrl.api_url + "/api/avaliation/create", $scope.avaliations).
    success(function (data, status) {
        if (status == 200) {

            // coloca o id da questao e o id da avaliacao
            for (var question in $scope.avaliation_questions) {
                $scope.avaliation_questions[question].avaliation_id = data.id;
                $scope.avaliation_questions[question].question_id = question;

                // begin save avaliation_questions -------------------------
                $http.post(ApiUrl.api_url + "/api/avaliation_question/create", $scope.avaliation_questions[question]).
                success(function (data, status) {
                    if (status == 200) {

                        // coloca o id do item do questionario
                        for (var item in $scope.avaliation_question_items[question]) {
                            $scope.avaliation_question_items[question][item].avaliation_question_id = data.id;
                            $scope.avaliation_question_items[question][item].question_items_id = item;

                            // begin save avaliation_question_items --------
                            $http.post(ApiUrl.api_url + "/api/avaliation_question_item/create", $scope.avaliation_question_items[question][item]).
                            success(function (data, status) {
                                if (status == 200) {

                                    $scope.toaster = {
                                        type: 'success',
                                        title: 'Avaliação',
                                        text: 'Avaliação salva com sucesso!'
                                    };
                                    toaster.pop($scope.toaster.type, $scope.toaster.title, $scope.toaster.text);

                                } else {

                                    $scope.toaster = {
                                        type: 'error',
                                        title: 'Itens da questão',
                                        text: 'Erro encontrado ao salvar este item: status - ' + status
                                    };
                                    toaster.pop($scope.toaster.type, $scope.toaster.title, $scope.toaster.text);

                                }
                            }).
                            error(function (data, status) {
                                $scope.toaster = {
                                    type: 'error',
                                    title: 'Itens da questão',
                                    text: 'Erro de sistema'
                                };
                                toaster.pop($scope.toaster.type, $scope.toaster.title, $scope.toaster.text);
                            });
                            // end save avaliation_question_items ----------

                        }

                    } else {

                        $scope.toaster = {
                            type: 'error',
                            title: 'Questões da avaliação',
                            text: 'Erro encontrado ao salvar esta questão: status - ' + status
                        };
                        toaster.pop($scope.toaster.type, $scope.toaster.title, $scope.toaster.text);

                    }
                }).
                error(function (data, status) {
                    $scope.toaster = {
                        type: 'error',
                        title: 'Questões da avaliação',
                        text: 'Erro de sistema'
                    };
                    toaster.pop($scope.toaster.type, $scope.toaster.title, $scope.toaster.text);
                });
                // end save avaliation_questions ---------------------------
            }

        } else {

            $scope.toaster = {
                type: 'error',
                title: 'Avaliação',
                text: 'Erro encontrado ao salvar esta avaliação: status - ' + status
            };
            toaster.pop($scope.toaster.type, $scope.toaster.title, $scope.toaster.text);

        }
    }).
    error(function (data, status) {
        $scope.toaster = {
            type: 'error',
            title: 'Avaliação',
            text: 'Erro de sistema'
        };
        toaster.pop($scope.toaster.type, $scope.toaster.title, $scope.toaster.text);
    });
    // end save avaliations ------------------------------------------------
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente o `Angular` não possui um helper para requisições `síncronas`, se você consultar o [código fonte](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/httpBackend.js) do angular diretamente eu seu repositório consultando a linha `77` você pode verificar que na abertura do objeto XHR, no terceiro parâmetro é especificado um `true` qual especifica que a consulta será `asíncrona` enquanto você precisaria que isto estivesse como false.

Referência da linha 77:

```
xhr.open(method, url, true);
```

Para resolver seu problema a solução é fazer a requisição na mão e atribuir os valores ao seu escopo, segue um exemplo de [como criar requisições sincronas de forma nativa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests).

---

Referência: [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088153/how-to-http-synchronous-call-with-angularjs)

Comment: Eu diria "Felizmente", uma vez que requisições sincronas em ajax estão com os dias contatos.